How to use `sphinx.ext.intersphinx` to link to Python+Polars documentation?
intersphinx docs give as an example:
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None),
}

What is the right URL, similar to the above example, for Polars?

Trial and error reveals the following should work (if one wants to refer to stable Polars; otherwise, the appropriate modification would have to be made):
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'polars': ('https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable', None)
}

